# is there any easiest way to modify dependency management version

Tags: maven

i am in a situation to modify all the dependency management versions manually...

```
 <dependencymanagement>  
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>group-a</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-a</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version> 
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencymanagement>
```

i have more than 100 dependencies in the management which are not third party jars, all are project jars....
previously we have all the same versions,so we don't have any issues to modify....

now we introduced different versions for each module, for each and every time modifying the dependency management manually is some what difficulty...is there any easiest way to update by using the commands or any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) which allows you to execute goals in order to handle versions, check the list [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Comment: i checked but no goal was suitable for my req..is there any approach or suitable goal please...versions:display-dependency-updates this will be useful for third party libraries,but mine is not third party jars

Comment: Why not latest versions: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have 100-odd dependencies as you have mentioned, you should be using a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) like [nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/sites/artifactory/latest/). Once you deploy your dependencies to the repository manager, then what @patric-lc suggests will work.